# Is it okay to give one's under-rep chatbot special access to their chatroom for typical chatbot testing & such?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, chat, code-of-conduct

I've been told in Stack Overflow chat that it's not okay to give one's chatbots without enough rep special access to their room just so that it could chat. I took that advice and kept it at Meta Stack Exchange chat.

However, after some time when I was reminding a co-RO about the rule, a mod at MSE informed me that it's A-OK to give one's chatbots special access to their chatroom, even if it doesn't have enough rep... as long as the owner of the chatbot didn't receive any restrictions regarding chat *(such as chat-ban)*.

So my question is, is it okay to give under-rep chatbots special access to one's chatroom *(like a new one made for chatbot testing)* for the sake of testing it, playing with it *(following the CoC, of course)*, etc.? Is the answer site-specific?

---

Chat message as requested:

[image]

Edit: I wasn't aware that only moderators can grant under-rep account explicit write access. My case was actually chatbots with enough rep at the time of granting access, and falling below the required rep count afterwards.

Comment: It is site specific. Rules on Stack Overflow are vastly different from those on other sites. It is waaay easier to monitor users and bots on sites that are a fraction of what Stack Overflow is. (The chat server for just Stack Overflow is larger than the chat server for all the other sites). So yep, on Stack Overflow chat, it is preferred that you get the privilege to chat through legitimate means. But do remember to explicitly provide write access once they reach 21 rep, so even if they fall below the required rep level, they can still chat.

Comment: Oh...!, my 2-3 previous Comments got deleted, I hope this one is OK...: On a Test-Site or a "Test-Chatroom" in this Case, => Test-Users/Test-Programs/Test-Bots should be allowed..., and on SO/SE, irrelevant from Rep... It's about Testing...! (OK, I'm out...)

Comment: Note: Only moderators can give write access to a chat room to a user who has less than 20 reputation at the time that access is granted.

Comment: Which would make it extra fun for the main server. On MSO and MSE - there's a fairly clear set of folks to ask. For main chat, there's.... well everyone and getting consensus is a little more difficult

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since that's my name on the chat message being quoted:

I think [Bhargav Rao's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407481/is-it-okay-to-give-ones-under-rep-chatbot-special-access-to-their-chatroom-for#comment841752_407481) hits the nail on its head. Rules on Stack Overflow are different, hence my chat message also stating I don't know what you were told, or under what circumstances.  Do note that I was talking with a third user *about you* here, whose name is cropped out of the message, which contributed to me adding that disclaimer: I'm not familiar enough with the rules of SO chat, but it makes sense to me they may be different.

As for me not minding it much: My reasoning was the opposite of [rene's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407487/6380541). That rule of 'Do not do things with a sock-puppet account you wouldn't be able to do otherwise.' to me means that if the master account has earned the privilege to chat, and has the privilege to grant explicit write access, using the master to grant write access to a sock/chatbot isn't necessarily breaking that rule. It comes with a bunch of 'use responsibly' warnings. But as long as your master account can grant write access, giving write access to a sock chatbot *technically* doesn't break the rule. You would need to be a moderator to do it though, which slipped my mind at the time.

Comment: Yeah, @rene's interpretation doesn't make sense to me. The rule given clearly says that you can do the same thing with sock as you can with your regular account. The restriction is against doing anything you can't normally do--i.e. that which you couldn't do without a sock puppet.

Comment: I actually didn't crop out their username, their username was above, as they had more irrelevant messages :)

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Kindly keep the comments underneath the post related to this question and answer only. If you need to discuss the closure of a room on a different chat server, please post a question on that particular site meta instead.

Answer (score -2):

Let's not overcomplicate matters.

There is one golden rule for sock-puppets (and your chatbot account is your sock-puppet):

> Do not do things with a sock-puppet account you wouldn't be able to do otherwise.

In this case: Your chatbot account can't chat due to lack of the chat privilege. If it wasn't operated by you it would need to gain the privilege on its own first before it can chat. If instead you grant it chat access early on, you're allowing it to do a thing it wouldn't be able to on its own.

Clever as you are you'll probably argue that you'll ask someone else (a moderator) you know to <s>become Room Owner (RO)</s> do moderatery things in your room and then have them grant your bot chat-access. I assume you understand that this delegated sock-puppetry shouldn't be allowed either. That is sock-puppetry by proxy.

Let me clarify the chat privilege for KennyBot in the Den ( I don't have an active memory when that write-access was granted which [seems correct as it hasn't today](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0q4f.png)). KennyBOT gained its chat privilege by [suggesting edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/269324/kennybot?tab=activity). Before those edits were accepted KennyBOT couldn't chat. As a matter of fact [it is a chat user since the November 7th, 2014](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/269324/kennybot), the same day it reached 20 reputation.

Comment: Abbreviation that keeps being used...: "RO" = "Room Owner" ...? => = "Chatroom Admin"...? (I don't now what it means, just asking..., and trying to guess...)

Comment: @chivracq yes, I've clarified that

Comment: OK, perfect..., but maybe mention both the Abbreviation together with the full meaning, as @OP used "RO" / "co-RO"  in their Qt... - "I don't now what it means" = "I don't know what it means" in my previous Comment, I was too late for the 5min Edit "2nd-Chance"... 5min is way too short...!

Comment: You have to ask the OP to clarify what co-RO means. There is no such feature/role/privilege in SE chat.

Comment: Yeah, well, once "RO" is clear, then "co-RO" is not difficult to understand...

Comment: co-RO refers to another RO... that's it. I know this because I was an RO in the room the OP is referencing.